# How to get locale on iPhone in C++?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios, internationalization

Everything I see about iPhone localization is, unsurprisingly, in Objective-C. The project I'm working on is already written and working on iPhone using almost entirely C++, and we have a few complete translations already. All we need now, is a way to find out the locale/language code. On the computer, this is done using `getenv`, checking "LANG", or if that's not set "LC_ALL". This doesn't seem to work on the iPhone (neither is set to anything), so I need some other method.

As far as I can tell, the best way to do it with Objective-C is:

```
NSString* languageCode = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

But then I'd have to convert from `NSString*` to `char*`/`std::string` (which can be done, but it's generally annoying/messy). So I'm wondering, is there an easier way to get the locale from C++ directly?

**Here's what I ended up doing:**

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        #include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#endif
/* ... */
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        CFArrayRef localeIDs = CFLocaleCopyPreferredLanguages();
        if (localeIDs)
        {
            CFStringRef localeID = (CFStringRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(localeIDs, 0);
            char tmp[16];
            if (CFStringGetCString(localeID, tmp, 16, kCFStringEncodingUTF8))
                locale = std::string(tmp); //this is the std::string
            CFRelease(localeIDs);
        }
#endif
```

Comment: You can wrap that into a C++ class/function.

Comment: And why would you need to do that more than once?

Comment: When did I say I wanted to do it more than once? And yes, I suppose I could make a new file with just this in it, and using Objective-C++ - but it's still messy and annoying.

Comment: I thought if you do it just once then it's not a big deal.  I cannot imagine that your iPhone application has Objective-C to C++ layer.  In some places it must directly interact with Cocoa.  I'd just put it there and move on.

Comment: Well, mostly it uses SDL, which does most of that part. So there's just a few bridges, for things like music, getting the screen size, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to use CFLocaleGetValue()